# Google Maps in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, custom-fields

In Wordpress I have created a custom field 'LatLonPosition' which contains different positions in the following format '48.96N, 10.23W'.

I was wondering if it's possible to pull the custom field content so that it displays a google map on each posts of the coordinates.

I know you can download google map plugins, but I was hoping to do this with the custom field if possible.

Hope someone can help.

Thank heaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though i have started working on word-press and php but its quite possible what you are trying to achieve

You can use either

```
get_post_custom_values()
```

if you are not concerned with the uniqueness else word-press also provides `get_post_meta()`
here are the details

[Accessing post custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: If I got the output '48.96N, 10.23W' what would I put in my webpage to make '48.96N, 10.23W' display a map with those coordinates?

Comment: Once you have those lat and long you can use Google map API to pass them to Google MAP API and let Google to do work for you.see here how they have used the co-ordinates http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#LatLng